# I need to debug laravel 5.4 webservice code while it called from android application

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, debugging

I need to debug my PHP web service code while it called from android application I'm using laravel 5.4. so when the mobile application send the POST request to my web API I need to check the post array to find out what is the shape of the data comes from the android application so if there is any way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel Log service https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging

Like

```
Public function store(Request $request) { 
  Log::debug($request->all()); 
}
```

And you can concatenate some extra information if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

You can read this given link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        //
    }

    return parent::report($exception);
}
```